# EditText don't show Text when inserting

Tags: android

I publish a app in the google playstore. When someone install it from there, then he don't see text written, when type into the editText-Field. Seems so that the font-Value is white. Because when set on save, then the inserted Value would be correct saved to the database and be viewed in the list.

Here is the part of the edittext-field fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/wheeldiameter"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextWheelDiameter"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@drawable/box_background_drawable"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_24"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="0"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:padding="14dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

And here is my Color.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#BB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#018786</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="backgroundColor">#dddddd</color>
    <color name="light_blue">#0FA2EB</color>
    <color name="green">#3ED004</color>
</resources>
```

It is really msystery. When I start the app in the androidstudio with the simulator device, then the text is black and I see what I insert.

Is it depending from the drawableStart or from the background?

Comment: Do you have a night/dark version  of colors.xml?

Comment: No i havent. I have only this colors.xml

Comment: Can you override the night version of colors.xml, and explicitly add `<color name="black">#000000</color>` and test

Comment: Can you provide box_background_drawable for more context?

Comment: <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#cccccc"/>
</shape>

Comment: Thanks for your all help. It is my fail in the day/night color-definitions.

I change this and it works.